# Microsoft Word (Wildcards)

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I have a file with a couple thousands of sentences like this.The document is as the following:

BASIC CONCEPTS

BASIC CONCEPTS. PART 1

1. Pronouns

I, me - ich [iɦ]

you - du [dʊ]

he - er [ər]

2. Greetings. Salutations. Farewells

Hello! (fam.) - Hallo! [ha′lø:]

Hello! (form.) - Hallo! [ha′lø:]

4. Cardinal numbers. Part 1

0 zero - null [nʊl]

1 one - eins [aıns]

Now what I'm trying to do is the following:
I want to create a table in MS Word that has two columns and an unlimited number of rows. In the first column and second column I want to put:

I, me                             :ich [iɦ]

you                               :du [dʊ]

he                                :er [ər]

0 zero                            :null [nʊl]

...etc

Note that the words "BASIC CONCEPTS, BASIC CONCEPTS. PART 1, 1. Pronouns, 2. Greetings. Salutations. Farewells, 4. Cardinal numbers. Part 1" are not needed. Also, note that there are numbers in some of the words. Now, using Wildcards in find and replace, what is the formula to find only those two set of words.

p.s. I have edited the original question above so people can understand the problem more clearly and benefit from the solution.

For those who are interested in Wildcards option in MS Word and you have free time I advise you to read "Jack M. Lyon Wildcard Cookbook for MS Word".

Answer (score 0):

Make two copies of your text and do the following replaces
(Ctrl+H and "Replace All").

**To extract the first component**

Find what :  `- [a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}`
Replace with : Nothing (empty)

**To extract the second component**

Find what : `(*) - [a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}`
Replace with : `\1`

The wildcards search of Word is buggy, which is why the search strings
are not simpler.

Reference :
[Using wildcards](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_365/tips/using_wildcards.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the word document is such a mess that I can't organize it. It have more details than I explained. I didn't want to ask my question in a complicated manner, but it seems that I have to. I edited the entire question so people can understand the problem more clearly and benefit from the solution. Please bear with me.